# What does the March 2021 change to Azure AD B2B redemption process actually mean?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

At the [Azure Blog Site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/unmanaged-accounts-b2b-update/) and in the documentation in at least two places is the following statement:

> Beginning March 31, 2021, Microsoft will no longer support the
> redemption of invitations by creating unmanaged Azure Active Directory
> (Azure AD) accounts and tenants for B2B collaboration scenarios.

What does this mean?  Does this mean that "viral tenant provisioning" is going away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at this flow chart, this means that we'll no longer be doing step #9 creating viral users/tenants. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/redemption-experience#invitation-redemption-flow

Comment: OK, so what happens at step 8 - does it go automatically to step 10 or does the process end with failure after step 6 if OTP isn't enabled or?

Comment: I think the long term goal is to eliminate steps 8-10 altogether, but I don't know if we're doing that by March 2021.

Comment: Hmm.  So right now at least, the exact behavior after the March 2021 change isn't defined?

Comment: Let me check this and get back to you

Comment: any word on the status here?